# DataTable Delete row Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatable plugin for table when I am trying to delete current row, the first row getting delete from datatable and in search also that deleted row shoudnot display

this is my jQuery code:

```
var table = $('#stockistTable').DataTable();
index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
table.row(index.rowIndex-1).remove().draw( false );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a Jquery object of the entire row element and pass it in `row()` function of Datatable.

```
var table = $('#stockistTable').DataTable();
var removingRow = $(this).closest('tr');
table.row(removingRow).remove().draw();
```

Comment: What is Datatable version ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#stockistTable').DataTable();
    $('tr').on("click", function(e) {
       index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
       table.row( $(this) ).remove().draw();
     });
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
var table = $('#stockistTable').DataTable();
var index = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
table.fnDeleteRow(table.fnGetPosition(index));
```

[Fiddle Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0afkg0gy/3/)

Comment: iam getting this error fnGetPosition is not a function

Comment: yes... i have included but in latest plugin does fnGetPosition supports?

Answer (score 1):

```
  var dtRow=0;  //declare this globally
  dtRow = $(this).closest('tr');  //assigning value on click delete
  var stockistTable=$('#stockistTable').DataTable();
  stockistTable.row(dtRow).remove().draw( false );
```

This Code worked for me!!!!

Answer (score -1):

This example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) demonstrates how to delete rows from a click event - it should do the trick for you.